# How can i add an action button to action bar

Tags: android

I'm new to Android developing.
Can someone explain how to add action button into this class if it is possible?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    HomeViewModel homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
    homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

and xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: what do you really wants to do ? add an action button but where ? in the toolbar ? ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize U.I of your Action Bar, then you can use Toolbar as Action Bar. Here are the steps to do the same:

// create an action bar button

@Override
public boolean on CreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

// R.menu.mymenu is a reference to an xml file named mymenu.xml which should be inside your res/menu directory.

// If you don't have res/menu, just create a directory named "menu" inside res

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

implement mymenu.xml in this way

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:title="Add"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:icon="@drawable/mybuttonicon"
/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

override this method in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
 return true;
 }
```

for this you have to create a menu named "home" in your menu folder (if you don't see a menu folder please create one inside res)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an action button over the toolbar, you have to:

1. Create the menu and the related item inside the menu folder:

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item
           android:id="@+id/action_add"
           android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
           android:title="Add"
           app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
   </menu>
   ```

NOTE: In this example, I added a button to add an element;

2. You have to inflate the menu inside the MainActivity class:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_menu, menu);
       return true;
   }
   ```
3. Then you can add action over the button

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_add){
           //Do something
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```

I Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you want to add onCreateOptionsMenu, you should press CTRL + O to open the dialog window, then type in onCreateOptionsMenu and choose it.

Let the Android Studio creates the code in a related and necessary place. (Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh4YOj9VkVE )

So, you may write the true code, on the wrong paranthesis.